# relative pronoun position

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

When I use relative pronoun position. I wonder which position like 1,2 below are grammatically or commonly proper sentence.

**Situation:**

There are easy words for Jim to understand without using a dictionary.

Jim is a native English speaker.

> 1.These are easy words for Jim to understand without using dictionary **who is a native English speaker**.
>
> 2.These are easy words for Jim **who is a native English speaker** to understand without using dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you try to keep the pronoun close to the noun it is representing.

Your second sentence is better, and the relative clause can be set off by commas

> These are easy words for Jim, who is a native English speaker, to understand without using a dictionary.